# replacing multiple characters in string with random digits/uppercase/lowercse Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a string,

```
str = 'B?l35?uAA8-A47E-4?d?d5-?d?dDC-C?dC?d?d?d?dF?lF?dE'
```

i want to replace all `?d` with random digits, all `?l` with random lowercase, all `?u` with random uppercase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: What is your actual question?  "Write this code for me" is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.randint()` and `random.choice()` to get random values for digits and alphabets. The variable inside `choice` has to be a list of all the alphabets.

You search through the full string one char at a time, then for each `?l` or `?u` or `?d`, you can replace the string with the desired result.

Here's a sample code I wrote to do this. Obviously, it can be improved but I wanted to give you a basic code to work with.

```
import random
s = 'B?l35?uAA8-A47E-4?d?d5-?d?dDC-C?dC?d?d?d?dF?lF?dE'
r = list(s)
a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
print (s)
for i,x in enumerate(s):
    if x == '?':
        if s[i+1] == 'l':
            r[i+1] = random.choice(a)
        elif s[i+1] == 'u':
            r[i+1] = random.choice(a).upper()
        elif s[i+1] == 'd':
            r[i+1] = str(random.randint(0,9))
r = ''.join(x for x in r if x != '?')
print (r)
```

Output of the above code for multiple runs are:

```
B?l35?uAA8-A47E-4?d?d5-?d?dDC-C?dC?d?d?d?dF?lF?dE
Be35ZAA8-A47E-4415-10DC-C9C0915FjF7E

B?l35?uAA8-A47E-4?d?d5-?d?dDC-C?dC?d?d?d?dF?lF?dE
Bl35DAA8-A47E-4985-26DC-C9C0455FxF6E

B?l35?uAA8-A47E-4?d?d5-?d?dDC-C?dC?d?d?d?dF?lF?dE
Bn35KAA8-A47E-4235-70DC-C1C5504FuF0E
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering i was doing it by search and replace this seems better

Comment: If the solution answered your question, don't forget to upvote my answer.